# Jquery click doesn't work after updating with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have read some about my problem and still don't get the right answer.I tried .on() method it still doesn't work.I am using Laravel.

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
   <tr class="item{{$order['menus']['id']}}">
       <td>{{$order['menus']['name'] }}</td>
       <td>{{$order['quantity']}}</td>
       <td>{{$order['quantity'] * $order['menus']['price']}}</td>
       <td><span id="paddingcustom"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus cancelbox " data-menuid="{{$order['menus']['id']}}"></span></span> </td>
       <td></td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

JS

```
$('.cancelbox').each(function(){
    $(this).on('click',function(){
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'menus/deleteTmp',
            data : {
                '_token' : $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                'id' : $(this).data('menuid'),
            },
            success : function ($data) {
                $('.item' + $data).remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Everything work I want after loading the page but when I update the elements by using replaceWith() methods and then onclick doesnt work.

I checked my updated html and attributes and all are in the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):-

So change::-

```
$('.cancelbox').each(function(){
  $(this).on('click',function(){
```

To::-

```
$(document).on('click','.cancelbox',function(){
```

So code need to be:-

```
$(document).on('click','.cancelbox',function(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'menus/deleteTmp',
        data : {
            '_token' : $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            'id' : $(this).data('menuid'),
        },
        success : function ($data) {
            $('.item' + $data).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Note:- now apply your `replaceWith()`code and check

Comment: @YanMyoAung  glad to help you. :):).